# Setting the right radio button as checked

Tags: php, variables, radio-button, set

Below is a function with a parameter that (in this example case) can contain either 'cat', 'dog' or 'bird'. The function contains of a form and I want to be able to set the right radio button as checked, depending on what option the variable $animal contains.

How could this be achieved in an elegant way?

```
public function SetAsChecked($animal) {
    // $animal = 'cat', 'dog' and 'bird'

    $html = "
            <form method='post'>
                <p>Option</p>
                <input type='radio' name='animals' value='1'> Cat<br />
                <input type='radio' name='animals' value='2'> Dog<br />
                <input type='radio' name='animals' value='3'> Bird<br />
            </form>";

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Note that I changed from $option to $animal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of options instead of repeating HTML:

```
public function SetAsChecked($animal){

    $options = array(
        '1' => 'Cat',
        '2' => 'Dog',
        '3' => 'Bird'
    );

    $optionsStr = '';

    foreach($options as $value => $name)
    {
        //$checked = $animal == $name ? 'checked' : ''; // use this if you want case sensitive comparison
        $checked = strcasecmp($animal, $name) == 0 ? 'checked' : ''; // case insensitive comparison
        $optionsStr .= "<input type='radio' name='options' value='$value' $checked />$name<br />";
    }

    $html = "
            <form method='post'>
                <p>Option</p>
                $optionsStr
            </form>";

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: +1 first answer to realize the passed variable wasn't the `value` but the text of the radio option. Probably want to make the comparison case insensitive based on OP's example.

Comment: Ah yes...we're not going by value but rather by text...how unusual. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'checked' attribute. This should work.
$optValue is the variable, the 'option' property is saved to.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 3; ++$i) $opchecked[$i] = "";    //Makes sure, that the variables are set.
$opchecked[$optValue] = 'checked';                //Sets the 'correct' option.

$html = "<form method='post'>
            <p>Option</p>
            <input type='radio' $opchecked[1] name='options' value='1'> Option1<br />
            <input type='radio' $opchecked[2] name='options' value='2'> Option2<br />
        </form>";
```

The most elegant method I can think of however is a function call.

```
function getRadio($Value, $Text) {
    $checked = (isset($_POST['animal']) && $Value == $_POST['animal']) ? "checked=checked" : "";
    return "<input type='radio' $checked name='animal' value='$Value'>$Text</input><br />";
}

$html = "<form method='post'>
            <p>Option</p>".
            getRadio(1, "Dog").
            getRadio(2, "Cat").
            getRadio(3, "Bird").
         </form>";
```

This function call will not select anything on the first call (because '$_POST['animal']' isn't set yet), but after that it will always keep the previously animal 'selected'. If you want to supply a 'default selection', add another parameter like this:

```
function getRadio($Value, $Text, $default) {
    if(!isset($_POST['animal']) && $default || isset($_POST['animal']) && $Value == $_POST['animal']) $checked = "checked=checked";
    else $checked = "";

    return "<input type='radio' $checked name='animal' value='$Value'>$Text</input><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the best way to do check marks and drop downs is after the fact is using javascript/jQuery, rather than looping through an array or doing other things.  Works very easy, just a few lines of code.

```
$("input[name=options][value=<?php echo $option; ?>]").attr("checked","checked");
```